# How do I write a PFQuery that will pull a PFObject and pull a sorted relation as well

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using the Parse.com iOS api. I have a 'User' table and a 'Session' table in parse. I have 'facebookid' column in 'User' and and a 'user' column in 'Session' (There is a one to many relation between User and Session). I'm having trouble writing a query that does the following: Given an array of 'facebookid', i'd like to pull down the 'User' associated with each 'facebookid' along with his most recent session. When I run the following code, I only get 1 'Session' object back, when I omit 'sessionQuery.limit = 1', I get all sessions associated with each user, not just the most recent.

```
PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
[userQuery whereKey:kFBUIDAttributeKey containedIn:fbids];
PFQuery *sessionQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kSessionParseObjectKey];
[sessionQuery includeKey:kUserParseAttributeKey];
sessionQuery.limit = 1;
[sessionQuery orderByDescending:kTimestampParseAttributeKey];
[sessionQuery whereKey:kUserParseAttributeKey matchesQuery:userQuery];
[sessionQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    complete(objects);
}];
```

I'm aware that I could make a separate request for each user but would prefer to do it in 1 request.

Comment: Could you clarify what is wrong with the 1 'Session' object that is being returned?

Comment: I want 1 session for each user, not 1 session for the entire query.

Comment: Parse has it's own little SO type section on their website. You couuld try asking your question over there. I found that their framework was a little too restrictive for me when it came to relational databases and joining tables and whatnot. I may be wrong, but I don't think you can do that without running multiple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you could get it back in one query is if you stored a reference to the most recent Session on the user, for example in a `mostRecentSession` property.

Then when you query, simply `[includeKey:][1]` as per the API.

This follows the principle of making your writes a little more complex (update mostRecentSession), and making reads much easier (no more nasty "select first object from large list sorted by time descending" per row).